# List effect android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list in my app. I have put a shape like background of the list but when a touch to do the scroll something works bad because the background turns black and the shape background not appear. Can somebody help me? Thank you. Here is my code:

listcode:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/fondo_menu"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
         />
```

list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"

        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#2df1bc"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

Comment: do you want the background to apply to every cell in the ListView?

Comment: I want to apply the background to the all ListView not to each list item, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add below attribute to listView

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:background="@drawable/fondo_menu"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute on the `ListView` Tag

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

or use it programmatically as

```
left_drawer.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
left_drawer.requestFocus(0);
```